# javascript add one minute to time object

Tags: javascript, time

I have a date string that looks like the following javascript format.
I want to convert this to a date object and add one minute.

```
timeObject = "Mon Nov 07 2011 06:41:48 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)";


timeObject.setSeconds(timeObject.getSeconds() + 60);
```

====== SOLUTION ==========

never mind. I got it...

```
var time = $('#myDiv').val();     // = "Mon Nov 07 2011 06:41:48 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)";
var timeObject = new Date(time);                
alert(timeObject);
timeObject.setSeconds(timeObject.getSeconds() + 60);    
alert(timeObject);
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: system would not let me. not enough points.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Proper way is:

```
timeObject.setTime(timeObject.getTime() + 1000 * 60);
```

Comment: If the provided value doesn't contain a correct datetime value, but only times (ex. 06:42), use

var timeObject = new Date("2000-01-01 " + time); 

to get a valid datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be using `.setMinutes()`:

```js
timeObject.setMinutes(timeObject.getMinutes() + 1)
```

Even if adding `n` minute(s) would cause a change of hour/day/month/year, the `Date` object already calculates this for you so you don't have to worry. Check [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAKG6SALgAQAmyBsRAvEWLAO5EAi5s6ARALLhEByIANyIAGAOxEATMICM0kQDYAXABZpKgBxEA4pwAqAWmEBWYcKLoAosggVUYIgGUCyMGVQkiugJYBbWJnYcfCg4eGgQAHN0MgoAGlJWeAjYAk4vMABXCggsHBiECBS0zOzoxOTU9KzYHMwiAGoiAGZhIPAQhHCo-Pj8pKKq0sxMIA) for an example.

Comment: You're wrong @ganzux. `setMinutes()` (and any other `setMETHOD()` for that matter) already calculates this for you. Check [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAKG6SALgAQAmyBsRAvEWLAO5EAi5s6ARALLhEByIANyIAGAOxEATMICM0kQDYAXABZpKgBxEA4pwAqAWmEBWYcKLoAosggVUYIgGUCyMGVQkiugJYBbWJnYcfCg4eGgQAHN0MgoAGlJWeAjYAk4vMABXCggsHBiECBS0zOzoxOTU9KzYHMwiAGoiAGZhIPAQhHCo-Pj8pKKq0sxMIA) out for more information. Please check if your conclusions are correct before telling everyone about them.

Comment: you are absolutely right, I am editing that to not get anyone confused.