# Adding one minute to current time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I use `Date` object to create time in my `Javascript` code and it should be formated like so : `08:04:21`. This is how I tried to do it:

```
$('#time').click(function(){
                var currentTime = new Date();
                var Time=currentTime.getHours() + ":"
                + currentTime.getMinutes() + ":"
                + currentTime.setSeconds(currentTime.getSeconds() + 60);
                console.log(Time);
                $(this).val(Time);
            });
```

But when `Time` is logged in console string looks like this `8:1:1467844916075`. Same happens when i try this:

```
var Time=currentTime.getHours() + ":"
                    + currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + 1) + ":"
                    + currentTime.getSeconds();
```

It bring out similar result : 8:1467844916075:3. I even tried this answer: [javascript add one minute to time object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036091/javascript-add-one-minute-to-time-object)

```
$('#time').click(function(){
                var currentTime = new Date();
                var Time = currentTime.setTime(currentTime.getTime() + 1000 * 60);
                console.log(Time);
                $(this).val(Time);
            });
```

But Time in this case looks like this: `1467785566719`. Any idea how to get human readable current time(not date) plus one minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this,

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var Time = currentTime.setTime(currentTime.getTime() + 1000 * 60);
console.log(Time);

var date = new Date(Time);
// Hours part from the timestamp
var hours = date.getHours();
// Minutes part from the timestamp
var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
// Seconds part from the timestamp
var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

// Will display time in 10:30:23 format
var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
console.log(formattedTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check this:

`Date.getTime()` returns you the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01.
So just grab it and add 1 minute to it to form new milliseconds count for new date.

```js
var d = new Date();
var millisecondssince1970 = d.getTime();
var newMillisec = millisecondssince1970 + (1000 * 60);

var newDate = new Date(newMillisec);

console.log(newDate.getHours() + ":"
                    + newDate.getMinutes() + ":"
                    + newDate.getSeconds());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/oa7j3krs/2/

```
$('#time').click(function(){
    var d = new Date($.now()+60*1000); // current time + 60s
    $(this).val(d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes()+':'+d.getSeconds());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I found a way to do this. Maybe it's not the best but it will do the job.

```
$('#time').click(function(){
                var currentTime = new Date();
                var addOneMinute = currentTime.getMinutes();
                addOneMinute=parseInt(addOneMinute) + 1;
                var Time=currentTime.getHours() + ":"
                + addOneMinute + ":"
                + currentTime.getSeconds();
                console.log(Time);
                $(this).val(Time);
            });
```