# Adding increment/decrement arrows to a input type=time

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, spinner

I need to find a way to customize a time input so that instead of the clock spinner, it has increment/decrement arrows.

I want the input to still show the time format: 00:00 AM/PM but I want to replace the spinner with functional up/down arrows, so basically a mix between a time input and a number input.

Any idea how I can achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you read [ask] first?

Comment: "_I need_", "_I want_", "_any idea how_" are not questions suitable for SO. Please read about [your obligation here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/9078341)

Comment: Seems like it would be easy enough. An `<input type="time">`, a couple of `<button type="button">`s. Event handlers on the buttons would increment and decrement the time value (see e.g., [javascript add one minute to time object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8036091/215552)). Where are you getting stuck?